# Find longest interval if the intervals can propagate from one to another

Tags: algorithms, binary-search, intervals

Let's say we have given $n$ points on the x-axis, each point described with two integers: $x_i, a_i$, $x_i$ meaning it's position on the x-axis, and $a_i$ meaning that it can activate all the points that lie in the range $[x_i, x_i + a_i]$.

The problem is for each of those n points to find the maximum number of points it will activate (note that the activation propagates for one to another point).

For example we have 4 point: $x = \{1, 2, 8, 10\}, a =\{7, 3, 8, 2\}$ The first point will activate the second and the third, the third point will then activate the last 4th point. The second point wont activate any points, only itself, the third point will activate the 4th point and the last point wont activate any points rather that itself. So the result should be this array: $\{4,1,2,1\}$

I noticed that the activated points will form a subarray starting in each index $i$ and now we might check with binary search, but I don't know how to check if each point is going to be activated or not. Please give me some hints where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to get started, so I will give you advice on how to get started:

> Start by trying each of the algorithm design paradigms you know: divide and conquer, dynamic programming, greedy, etc.  One of those will work -- I will let you have the joy of discovering the details.

Another hint, if you get stuck after trying that one:

> Try to work out some small examples by hand.  If you were going to fill in the results array in some order, what order would make it easiest to do that?  If you were going to process the points in some order, what order would make it easier to figure out the answer for each point as you process it (taking into account the answer for points you've previously processed)?  Can you spot a pattern.

This should be enough that you should be able to work out a solution.